# Increasing of model size leads to poor backward performance (Pytorch)

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I built ResNet - like model with Pytorch 1.11.
I use a machine with 2 CPU (12 cores), 72 GB memory, no GPU.

While trainig the following results were obtained:

| params | forward, s | backward, s |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 76 929 892 | 2,81 | 7,1 |
| 80 075 818 | 3,14 | 7,76 |
| 83 322 861 | 3,32 | 7,95 |
| 86 634 044 | 3,45 | 8,47 |
| 90 009 367 | 3,58 | 8,86 |
| 93 516 104 | 3,47 | 8,92 |
| 96 979 046 | 3,90 | 9,23 |
| 100 547 209 | 4,01 | 9,93 |
| 104 179 512 | 4,27 | 10,19 |
| 107 875 955 | 4,31 | 244,46 |
| 111 710 028 | 4,17 | 255,14 |

Seems like I achieved limitation of some resource, L3 cache?

Any ideas how to resolve it?